# This is my code , it keeps giving me this error : declaration error undeclared identifier solidity , did u mean "value"? line ( return _value)

Tags: solidity, declaration, remix, undeclared-identifier

```
pragma solidity 0.8.13;

contract student {
    string public value;

    constructor() public {
        value="sami";
    } 
    
    function set(string memory _value) public {
        value = _value;
    }
    
    function get() public view returns(string memory) {
        return _value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined var in get() function "_value". MAy be you what return class var "value"?

Comment: Thanks brother , i fixed that and then said another error occured and then i was able to fix that thanks brother

Comment: You are wellcome. Can you accept my answer?